# Convert Array of Dictionary to custom object swift

Tags: ios, swift

**I have:**

```
    let countries : [[String : Any]] = [
            [
                "name" : "Afghanistan",
                "dial_code": "+93",
                "code": "AF"
            ],
            [
                "name": "Aland Islands",
                "dial_code": "+358",
                "code": "AX"
            ],
            [
                "name": "Albania",
                "dial_code": "+355",
                "code": "AL"
            ],
            [
                "name": "Algeria",
                "dial_code": "+213",
                "code": "DZ"
            ]
]
```

**I want to add all this array of dictionary to my custom object like**

```
let country:[Country] = countries
```

**My custom object looks like this:**

```
class Country: NSObject {
        let name: String
        let dial_code : String
        let code: String

        init(name: String, dial_code: String, code: String) {
            self.name = name
            self.dial_code = dial_code
            self.code = code
        }
    }
```

I understand that I need a loop thru the array but idk what is the next step. Would be great to have an example.

Comment: `var countries = [Country](); for countryDict in countries { let aCountry = Country.init(name: countryDict["name"] dial_code:countryDict["dial_code"] code:countryDict[code"]); countries.append(aCountry);}`. Code written here, might not compile but it's to give you the idea.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any reason to inherit from NSObject. I would suggest using a struct for this simple data type

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You should make your Country conform to `Codable` protocol, convert your dictionary to JSON data using `JSONSerialization` and then just decode the `Data` using `JSONDecoder`, note that you can set its `keyDecodingStrategy` property to `convertFromSnakeCase` auto avoid the need to declare custom coding keys like `dial_Code`:

```
struct Country: Codable {
    let name: String
    let dialCode : String
    let code: String
}
```

---

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: countries)
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    let decodedCountries = try decoder.decode([Country].self, from: json)
    decodedCountries.forEach{print($0)}
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

---

> Country(name: "Afghanistan", dialCode: "+93", code: "AF")
>
> Country(name: "Aland Islands", dialCode: "+358", code: "AX")
>
> Country(name: "Albania", dialCode: "+355", code: "AL")
>
> Country(name: "Algeria", dialCode: "+213", code: "DZ")

Comment: Why do you nest the `do-catch`?

Comment: Classic Xcode. As OP is seems pretty inexperienced, maybe change it to how it "should" be so we don't teach him the wrong patterns?

Comment: Also, you can do `countries.forEach(print)`, a little bit cleaner.

Comment: Hm. Works for me. Can't explain that.

Comment: @OscarApeland `forEach(print)` doesn't work, because of the signature of [`print`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1541053-print): `func print(_ items: Any..., separator: String = default, terminator: String = default) `. Unfortunately, the compiler doesn't automatically generate thunks that fill in defaulted arguements, so print (which has type `(Any..., String, String) -> Void` can't be treated as `(Any...) -> Void`, as would be necessary for passing it into `forEach`.

Answer (score 7):

**Not related  but remove `NSObject` until you are required**

That is very simple thing you just need to think a bit

Create Object like this

```
var arr = [Country]()
```

Now Loop your array of dictionary

```
  for dict in countries {
      // Condition required to check for type safety :)
        guard let name = dict["name"] as? String, 
              let dialCode = dict["dial_code"] as? String, 
              let code = dict["code"] as? String else {
              print("Something is not well")
             continue
         }
        let object = Country(name: name, dial_code:dialCode, code:code)
         arr.append(object)
    }
```

That's it  You have converted array of dict to Custom Object

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I would extract this code into a new initializer of `country`

Comment: @Alexander I didn't get you !! , Yes you need to create `Country` object for every item in array

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya I'm saying that this `guard let` code should be in its own initializer. Perhaps `Conutry.init(fromDict: [String: String])`

Comment: @Alexander Yes We can !!  But for that we need to create of optional  `Country` object  as `Country` init may not been created if full detail not passed. So I picked a straight and simple way

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya So use a failable initializer. See my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160725/discussion-between-alexander-and-prashant-tukadiya).

Comment: "Create Global Object like this" You mean create an instance property in your view controller. A "Global Object" would be accessible anywhere in your code.

Comment: @LeoDabus  Actually that's depend on the requirement !! , If you have custom class and returning the value to other class then no need to create global object . if you are showing that data somewhere like tableview then you need global object. That's totally on  requirement

Comment: Don't do that. You can pass the data using prepare for segue method or create a Singleton

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes if you want to pass data somewhere then you are right. But you have all logic on same screen then you need global object. Here nothing mentioned here that he need to use segue or has helper classes for webservice

Comment: I suggest you take a look at AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/AdoptingCocoaDesignPatterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH7-ID177

Comment: @LeoDabus Please suggest the code with that i need to update my answer.  Yes I am aware about singleton but how to show it in this example

Comment: Just change it as I suggested in my first comment. It should be declared as an instance property of the view controller.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`flatMap`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1540500-flatmap) method of a list to produce the result:

```
countries.flatMap { (v: [String: Any]) -> Country? in
    if let name = v["name"] as? String, 
       let dial = v["dial_code"] as? String, 
       let code = v["code"] as? String {
        return Country(name: name, dial_code: dial, code: code)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

A full example would be:

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

let countries : [[String : Any]] = [
    [
        "name" : "Afghanistan",
        "dial_code": "+93",
        "code": "AF"
    ],
    [
        "name": "Aland Islands",
        "dial_code": "+358",
        "code": "AX"
    ],
    [
        "name": "Albania",
        "dial_code": "+355",
        "code": "AL"
    ],
    [
        "name": "Algeria",
        "dial_code": "+213",
        "code": "DZ"
    ]
]

class Country: NSObject {
    let name: String
    let dial_code : String
    let code: String

    init(name: String, dial_code: String, code: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.dial_code = dial_code
        self.code = code
    }
}

let cnt = countries.flatMap { (v: [String: Any]) -> Country? in
    if let name = v["name"] as? String, let dial = v["dial_code"] as? String, let code = v["code"] as? String {
        return Country(name: name, dial_code: dial, code: code)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

print (cnt)
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of answers already, but I find that there are short comings with most of them. This is what I would suggest:

```
extension Country {
    init?(fromDict dict: [String: Any]) {
        guard let name = dict["name"] as? String, 
              let dialCode = dict["dial_code"] as? String, 
              let code = dict["code"] as? String else {
            return nil
        }
        self.init(name: name, dialCode: dialCode, code: code)
    }
}

let countries = countryDictionaries.map { dict -> Country in
    if let country = Country(fromDict: dict) { return Country }
    else {
        preconditionFailure("Tried to convert an invalid dict into a country")
        // TODO: handle error appropriately
    }
}
```

If you just want to ignore invalid country dictionaries, that's even easier:

```
let countries = countryDictionaries.flatMap(Country.init(fromDict:))
```

Comment: Swift can infer which initializer matches the resulting type and flatMap has been replaced by compactMap as you know. `.compactMap(Country.init)`. Btw There is no dict parameter and casting from String to String is pointless.

Comment: @LeoDabus The param was meant to be `[String: String]`. This was written before `flatMap`. I'm not sure if I should update it. In new code, I would be doing this with codable, and not write any of this haha

Comment: You are still using the wrong parameter name. Regarding flatMap that’s why I said as you know. Btw Codable was already released when this was asked.

Comment: @LeoDabus Interesting, I have no idea why I didn't use that, then lol. In fairness, I was much more nooby 4 years ago haha :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful extension that infers the type from the pre-defined return type:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func castToObject<T: Decodable>() -> T? {
        let json = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self)
        return json == nil ? nil : try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: json!)
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
struct Person: Decodable {
  let name: String
}

let person: Person? = ["name": "John"].castToObject()
print(person?.name) // Optional("John")
```

Answer (score 1):

Very simple and clear solution:

- Create custom initializer with param json `[String : Any]` in your class `Country`.
- Init all variables of class using loop in custom initializer.

Try this code:

```
class Country: NSObject {
    var name: String = ""
    var dial_code: String = ""
    var code: String = ""

    // Sol: 1
    init(json: [String : Any]) {
        if let name = json["name"] as? String, let dial_code = json["dial_code"] as? String, let code = json["name"] as? String {
            self.name = name
            self.dial_code = dial_code
            self.code = code
        }
    }

    // or Sol: 2
    init(name: String, dial_code: String, code: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.dial_code = dial_code
        self.code = code
    }
}
```

- Create an instance of class `Countries` using element of array `countries` and collect the same in separate array `arrayOfCountries`

Try this code:

```
let countries : [[String : Any]] = [
    [
        "name" : "Afghanistan",
        "dial_code": "+93",
        "code": "AF"
    ],
    [
        "name": "Aland Islands",
        "dial_code": "+358",
        "code": "AX"
    ],
    [
        "name": "Albania",
        "dial_code": "+355",
        "code": "AL"
    ],
    [
        "name": "Algeria",
        "dial_code": "+213",
        "code": "DZ"
    ]
]

var arrayOfCountries = [Country]()

// Sol: 1
for json in countries {
    let country = Country(json: json)
    print("country name - \(country.name)")
    arrayOfCountries.append(country)
}

// Sol: 2
for json in countries {

    if let name = json["name"] as? String, let dial_code = json["dial_code"] as? String, let code = json["name"] as? String {
        let country = Country(name: name, dial_code: dial_code, code: code)
        print("country name - \(country.name)")
        arrayOfCountries.append(country)
    }

}
```

Comment: Better to use `map` than repeated appends in a for loop

Comment: @Alexander - thanks for your remark - let me see what's difference between both. Till date I've tried to check how map is better :)

Comment: 1) It's more concise, so it's more easy to see what's being done. 2) It allows `arrayOfCountries` to remain a `let` constant, unlike repeated-appends which force it to be a `var` variabele. 3) `map` automatically calls `Array.reserveCapcity(_:)`, so it removes allocation overhead that can really slow the repeated-append approach.

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom country class with param json [String : Any]

```
class Country: NSObject {
    var name: String?
    var dialCode: String?
    var code: String?

    init(json: [String : Any]) {
       self.name = json["name"] as? String
       self.dialCode = json["dial_code"] as? String
       self.code = json["code"] as? String
    }
}
```

Later you can map the dictionary into the array of country using

```
let _ = countries.flatMap { Country.init }
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to initialize an empty array type of Country Class

```
var countryArray = [Country]()
//then you have to loop thru the countries dictionary 
//and after casting them adding it to this empty array with class initializer  

countries.forEach { (dict) in

    countryArray.append(Country(name: dict["name"] as! String, dial_code: dict["dial_code"] as! String, code: dict["code"] as! String))

}
//this is how you reach to properties
countryArray.forEach { (country) in
    print(country.name)
}
```

Comment: Don't use `forEach` to do `append`! Just use `map`!

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: You don't need a separate line to define `countryArray`, you're not forced to have it be mutable, and `map` calls `reserveCapacity(_:)` to prevent reallocation overhead on array expansion.

Answer (score 0):

You can map the dictionary into the array. As a dictionary always returns an optional value for key (the value is not guaranteed to exist) you need a guard to make sure you proceed only if that is the case.

In this sample solution I throw if any of the values are not there - but this is really up to you to decide.

```
struct AnError: Error {}

do {
    let countryObjects: [Country] = try countries.map {
        guard let name = $0["name"] as? String,
              let dial_code = $0["dial_code"] as? String,
              let code = $0["code"] as? String else {throw AnError()}

        return Country(name: name, dial_code: dial_code, code: code)
    }
}
catch {
    //something went worng - handle the error
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use `Array.foreach` like this

```
countries.forEach{country.append(Country($0))}
```

and u may change `init` parameters of `Country` to `[String: Any]`,
or cast `$0` to `[String: Any]` and read ur values from it and send them to `init`

Comment: Don't use `forEach` to append! Just use `map`!